# How to determine uniquely an extremal of a variational problem

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

This is a question from a competitive examination:

Consider the functional $$ J(y) = \int_{a}^b (y+y^{'})dx $$
for admissible functions y, Then $J$ has:

1. No extremals.
2. Several extremals.
3. $y(x)=e^{-x}$ as an extremal.
4. $y(x)=$ constant as an extremal.

What I have tried:

Using the Euler's second equation:
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \left(F - y^{'}\frac{\partial F}{ \partial y^{'} } \right) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0 $$

Since $F=y+y^{'}$ is independent of $x$, we get $$ F - y^{'}\frac{\partial F}{ \partial y^{'} } =c$$
$$ i.e. \hspace{2cm} y+y^{'}-y^{'}=c  \implies \hspace{.5cm} y=c$$
for some constant c.

But if I use Euler's first equation namely
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} -\frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial y^{'}} \right)=0 $$

I have $$ 1- \frac{d}{dx}(1)=0 \implies 1=0  $$
Thus no extremal exists.

*The answer is no extremal exists.*

So can someone please provide some insights into this nature of the extremal.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by an extremal?

Comment: An extremal is a curve which minimizes or maximizes the value of the functional.

Comment: Is $y^{'}$ in your notation just the derivative?

Comment: What is the space of admissible functions?

Comment: Admissible functions are functions which pass through given initial points namely $y(a)=y_0$ and $y(b)=y_1$. But this is not provided in the question.

Comment: The second Euler's equation is a consequence of the first, i.e. it's true when the first is true. Because the first is false, then nothing is clear about the second. So the correct answer is that there are no extremals in this problem.

Comment: @almosteverywhere yes it is the derivative.